# scrollTop only measures from top of scrollbar, need entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, height, scrolltop

I'm trying to pass the percentage that a user has scrolled on a page as a var ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AndDZ/)). `$(document).scrollTop() / $(document.height() * 100` is great for starting at 0 -- the top of the page -- but when you get to the bottom, it only returns the position at the top of the scrollbar, not 100%. See fiddle to see what I mean.

Does anyone know a way to get 0 at the top and 100 at the bottom? Main thing is it has to be calculated on-the-fly: if someone's at 45.2667% of the page, I want that value passed as opposed to just at the top or at the bottom.

Comment: Just minus the windows height from the pages height before calculating % ? Then you only need to check for window bigger than page => negative height => set to whatever % you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get the percentage from top of the page to top of the scrollbar when scrolled to bottom. Try:

```
($(document).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) * 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Sactor is correct but it won't work for all the positions.

If you want to consider the end of page too, I take that you want to calculate the amount of page "viewed" not "scrolled"

If you are considering the amount of page viewed not the amount of scrolled then you can use the following:

Logically when you just open the page you view some amount of the page. So you can always get,

```
( ( $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() ) / $(document).height() ) * 100
```

Else:

If you want the scroll alone, then use

```
var extreme = $(document).height() - $(window).height(),
percent = 0;
if( $(document).scrollTop() <  extreme )
   percent = $(document).scrollTop() / $(document.height() * 100;
else
   percent = 100;
```

Comment: I couldn't get your formula to work the way I wanted it to (the script I'm using redraws a canvas on event scroll -- a little more complex than just changing the .var) but it does work in the fiddle. Sactor's worked in the script I'm using. Thanks, though.